# totalling input values in div columns with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following column structure:

```
<div class="column">
    <span class="header">Column 1</span>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" value="1" required="required" name="foo1" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" value="1" required="required" name="foo2" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" value="1" required="required" name="foo3" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" value="1" required="required" name="foo4" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" value="1" required="required" name="foo5" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" value="1" required="required" name="foo6" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" value="1" required="required" name="foo7" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <span class="columnTotal">7</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 4 of these "columns" in a tabular structure.

What i am looking for is some way that when an input's value is changed, it totals all the other input values *in that column only* and puts the total in the span with the columnTotal class at the bottom of the column.

I know the jquery to hook onto any inputs change event, i'm just wondering how to get the other inputs in the same column. So far i can only get all the inputs or none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.inputs').keyup(function(){
var total = 0;
$(this).parent().parent().find("input").each(function(){
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
 $(this).parent().parent().find("span").html(total);
})
```

By doing this you can add as many columns as you want and it will still work. Its working with the keyup event, you can change it to the "change" event.

Here is the JsFiddle of the code working.

http://jsfiddle.net/4XZAu/

Comment: Here is an example with 4 colums as in your question.  http://jsfiddle.net/4XZAu/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
function addUp(){
    $(".column").each(function(){
        var total = 0;
        $(this).find(".cell input").each(function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $(this).find(".columnTotal").text(total);
    });
}
$("input").on("change keyup",function(){
    addUp();
});
addUp();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4937M/2/
Fiddle with second column: http://jsfiddle.net/4937M/3/

---

Explanation: Adds up inputs in each column, automatically recalculating on the `keyup` or `change` events. The selectors may need to be more specific depending on where you are using this. (e.g., the `input` selector for the event listener)

Comment: that looks like it might wor, but OP was looking for it on the `change` event

Comment: I bound it to the change and keyup events.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting an answer i came up with, seems to be working ok:

```
$(":text").change(function(){
    var column = $(this).parent().parent();
    var inputTotal = 0;
    var columnTotal = 0;
    column.find(":text").each(function(){
        inputTotal += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
    columnTotal = (inputTotal / 7).toFixed(1);
    column.find(".columnTotal").text(columnTotal);
});
```

Thanks to those that answered.